# Rebuilding indexes in Mongodb 

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm reading about [Mongodb's indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes) for my Mongodb project

I am well aware that inserting data into a traditional relation database would cause a large slow down if the table was very large as the indexes are rebuilt.

If I choose to add indexes to Mongodb collections: **Is rebuilding an index in Mongodb roughly as expensive as rebuilding an index in a traditional relational database?** or does the fact that it uses a [B-Tree for indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-Basics) improve rebuild time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilding an index is just as expensive in Mongodb.

Note: traditional databases also use B-Trees.

Answer (score 3):

In MongoDB, as in other RDMBS, once you build an index, subsequent inserts, deletes, and updates will be slowed down.

The process of rebuilding is handled by MongoDB itself, but you can force a manual rebuild using `db.myCollection.reIndex()`.

Comment: A fair warning for anyone thinking about using `reIndex`, the command is deprected since version 6, and only affects standalone instances since version 5.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.reIndex/#definition